# gil sans light font in website

Tags: javascript, css, fonts

I have been asked to change the font throughout a website into Gil Sans Light. Is there anyway I can preload this font using javascript or some other utility to get it working across browsers - currently I can only see it in Dreamweaver and not on the live site regardless of browser (tried Safari, Firefox, Chrome and IE).....

I have seen it before where someone has loaded in a font using some js but have no idea where to look for something like this.

Thanks for any advice or guidance in advance

JD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with pure CSS by using @font-face.

You can even convert your font: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Although you need to check out whether the license allows it to be embedded on the web.

Comment: thanks! went through all possibilities put up - all valid methods for others reading this post.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read any articles about JS font libraries? [I found this one for you.](http://talentopoly.com/questions/68-which_js_font_library_should_i_use)

Comment: thanks! went through all possibilities put up - all valid methods for others reading this post.

Answer (score 0):

something to start with:

- http://typekit.com/
- http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader.html
- http://webfonts.fonts.com/en-US/Project/ChooseFonts?ViewFontID=692628

Comment: thanks! went through all possibilities put up - all valid methods for others reading this post.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Google Web Fonts:
http://www.google.com/webfonts

Not sure if they have the font you are looking for but might have an alternative.

Comment: thanks! went through all possibilities put up - all valid methods for others reading this post.